# For MASM, what kind of output is this asking for?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

[image: From Kip Irvine's Intel x86 Assembly Language]

I'm confused as to what this problem is asking for as an output. Can anyone clarify? You do not need to solve the problem. I just need help understanding what it is asking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing there is a linked list where:

- `1` is the starting index;
- each character is the payload;
- each link is the `next` pointer.

It may be better to think of it as:

```
start = 1
index:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
char:     H  A  C  E  B  D  F  G
next:     0  4  5  6  2  3  7  0
```

and realise that:

- The starting index of `1` gives you the character `A` and a link of `4`.
- That index of `4` gives you the character `B` and a link of `2`.
- That index of `2` gives you the character `C` and a link of `5`.
- That index of `5` gives you the character `D` and a link of `3`.
- And so on.

Rearranging them sorted on list (following `start/next`) order gives you:

```
start = 1
index:    1  4  2  5  3  6  7  0
char:     A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H
next:     4  2  5  3  6  7  0  0
```

So it's effectively the linked list:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H -> H -> H ...
```

The expected result should just be the linked list in order (`ABCDEFGH`) copied to a new array but, interestingly enough, `H` points to itself rather than some special NULL value, so you will have to detect that as a special case.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo! Everything explained so well. It was the G char pointing to 0 that confused me! But seeing as it's pointing to 0 as H and H pointing to itself that makes sense.